# How can I get the size of a library/executable's executable code section?

Tags: security, executable, ldd

I'm performing an analysis of the executable sizes of various codebases, and I'm looking to get data about how large the executable section of a library or executable is. I know I can sort of get an idea by looking at `/proc/xxx/maps`, but is there anything that will explicitly tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `size xxx` will give that to you.